# Jquery AJAX Deferred not working?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following:

```
var archiveFolders = function (ids) {
     var options = {// stuff}
     return $.ajax(options)
}

archiveFolders(data).then(alert("heyo"));
```

But "heyo" is getting displayed immediately after the call to archiveFolders, NOT after the call finishes.  How to I wait to display "heyo" until I get a response from the server?

Comment: Is your AJAX call actually happening?

Comment: yes, I see a breakpoint get hit on the serverside AFTER the alert is thrown

Comment: Provide a full reproducible example.

Comment: Give me an AJAX endpoint to hit

Comment: Nevermind, I see the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is actually quite simple.  `alert("heyo")` is evaluated immediately.  Try this instead:

```
archiveFolders(data).then(function () {
  alert("heyo");
});
```